# Meteor cannot start

Tags: node.js, meteor, certificate

I am trying to run meteor project on windows 10 (localhost)
Meteor version: 1.8.0.2

```
While downloading accounts-base@1.4.3...:
error: certificate has expired

   While downloading accounts-password@1.5.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading alanning:roles@1.2.16...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading aldeed:collection2@3.0.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading aldeed:schema-index@3.0.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading autoupdate@1.5.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading babel-compiler@7.2.4...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading babel-runtime@1.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading base64@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading blaze@2.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading blaze-html-templates@1.1.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading blaze-tools@1.0.10...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading boilerplate-generator@1.6.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading caching-compiler@1.2.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading caching-html-compiler@1.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading callback-hook@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:access-point@0.1.49...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:base-package@0.0.30...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:collection@0.5.5...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:collection-filters@0.2.4...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:data-man@0.0.6...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:file@0.1.17...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:http-methods@0.0.32...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:http-publish@0.0.13...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:power-queue@0.9.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:standard-packages@0.5.10...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:storage-adapter@0.2.4...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:tempstore@0.1.6...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:upload-http@0.0.20...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading cfs:worker@0.1.5...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading coffeescript@1.0.17...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ddp-client@2.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ddp-server@2.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading deps@1.0.12...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading dynamic-import@0.5.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ecmascript@0.12.4...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ecmascript-runtime@0.7.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ecmascript-runtime-client@0.8.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ecmascript-runtime-server@0.7.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ejson@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading email@1.2.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading fetch@0.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading fourseven:scss@4.10.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading html-tools@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading htmljs@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading http@1.4.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading id-map@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading inter-process-messaging@0.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading jquery@1.11.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading kadira:blaze-layout@2.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading kadira:flow-router@2.12.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading launch-screen@1.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading livedata@1.0.18...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading logging@1.1.20...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading meteor@1.9.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading meteor-base@1.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading meteorhacks:ssr@2.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading minifier-css@1.4.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading minifier-js@2.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading minimongo@1.4.5...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mizzao:build-fetcher@0.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mizzao:jquery-ui@1.11.4...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mobile-experience@1.0.5...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mobile-status-bar@1.0.14...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading modern-browsers@0.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading modules@0.13.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading modules-runtime@0.10.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading momentjs:moment@2.24.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mongo@1.6.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mongo-decimal@0.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mongo-id@1.0.7...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading mquandalle:jquery-ui-drag-drop-sort@0.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.9.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading npm-mongo@3.1.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading observe-sequence@1.0.16...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ostrio:cookies@2.3.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ostrio:files@1.10.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading promise@0.11.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading raix:eventemitter@0.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading raix:ui-dropped-event@0.0.7...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading random@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading reactive-dict@1.2.1...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading reload@1.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading risul:bootstrap-colorpicker@2.3.6...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading routepolicy@1.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading service-configuration@1.0.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading shell-server@0.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading simple:json-routes@2.1.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading socket-stream-client@0.2.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading softwarerero:accounts-t9n@1.3.11...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading spacebars@1.0.15...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading spacebars-compiler@1.1.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading srp@1.0.12...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading standard-minifier-css@1.5.2...:
   error: certificate has expired
   
   While downloading standard-minifier-js@2.4.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading templating@1.3.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading templating-compiler@1.3.3...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading templating-runtime@1.3.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading templating-tools@1.1.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading themeteorchef:bert@2.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading tmeasday:check-npm-versions@0.3.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading tmeasday:publish-counts@0.8.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading ui@1.0.13...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading url@1.2.0...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading useraccounts:core@1.14.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading webapp@1.7.2...:
   error: certificate has expired

   While downloading webapp-hashing@1.0.9...:
   error: certificate has expired

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

**Note:** I have tried **process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0**; but problem is still still there.

Comment: Node on Windows é very slow to add libs. I think that you can use a VM or a Docker to run your Meteor code.

Comment: For the expired certificate, you need to export the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED in your environment. I don't know how is on a Windows machine.

Comment: You can also try to use WSL2 on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the app,
run:

> set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may try to explain with more details how your answer could help him, because he already said that  **I have tried process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0**